# Add class to object on mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add the class "selected" when clicking on a div. The problem is that if i am clicking on a div that has a parent div. the parent gets selected, not the children div i want to select.

I want to be able to click the parent div without the children div to be selected and click a children div without any parents of that div getting selected.
Only 1 div should have the selected class at once. The divs are also resizable and draggable.

```
$("#wrapper").delegate('div:not(".ui-resizable-handle")', 'mousedown', function() {
      $(".drag").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6wYRF/3/   ...Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of event propagation, prevent it by returning `false` from the event handler

```
$(".drag").draggable();
$(".drag").resizable();

$("#wrapper").delegate('div:not(".ui-resizable-handle")', 'mousedown', function() {
    $(".drag").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8vsmu/)

Comment: While you are right about the event propagation, your fiddle still highlights the outer div. Either change #wrapper to .drag or use e.target like pXL's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".drag").draggable();
$(".drag").resizable();

$("#wrapper").delegate('div:not(".ui-resizable-handle")', 'mousedown', function (e) {
    $(".drag").removeClass('selected');
    if ($(e.target).is('.drag')) {
        $(e.target).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/6wYRF/7/

Answer (score 0):

Every event pass an object as parameter to the callback; this object has a target property which is the current element on which the event is generated on.

```
$("#wrapper").delegate('div:not(".ui-resizable-handle")', 'mousedown', function(evt) {
  $(".drag").removeClass('selected');
    $(evt.target).addClass('selected');

});
```